# Wordpress Responsive Nav Menu not working

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I have a navigation menu issue that I can't figure out for the life of me, but basically my responsive menu doesn't respond in order to reveal the li's underneath it.  The site is [healyourselfnecklaces.com](http://healyourselfnecklaces.com) and the menu switches at 600px

Any help you can give me, including how you found the issue, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any theme or is it your customized theme ?

Comment: Maybe post some code?

Comment: @Rohil- its a child theme of generate press, with primarily just CSS edits and a few minor plug ins

Comment: @Zombie [link](http://pastebin.com/46EMNiZK).  Im not exactly sure if it is an issue in the navigation.php or the header.php but Im basically looking for anything attached to the class .menu-toggle

Answer (score 0):

I believe you issue is that there is no JavaScript added to the menu button to toggle (show/hide) your menu when you are in a mobile view.